# Problemas con MySQL en XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

Cada vez que presiono **start** en el botón de `MySQL` en `XAMPP`,me parece este mensaje :

```
Status change detected: running
16:21:27  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
```

Y no pasa de ahí, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Primero que todo checa los log que te arroja! Revisa a ver que te puede ayudar este enlace:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279442/xampp-mysql-not-starting-attempting-to-start-mysql-service

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema común, se puede resolver abriendo `cmd` -> escribes `sc delete mysql` y ejecutas.

Luego abres el administrador de tareas, y en la pestaña de procesos buscas el proceso: `mysqld.exe` o `mysqld.exe (32bits)`

Cierras y abres xampp y debería estar solucionado.